# What does "assembly" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Madison: I just don't think it's a good idea, looking for some secret
> weirdo off the Internet. I mean, we just had an **assembly** about this.
>
> Josh: He's not a weirdo. He's a covert investigator.

What does "assembly" mean in this context?

Source: Godzilla vs. Kong (2021)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume these characters are teenagers; it sounds like they are talking about a school assembly, which is a regular gathering of the whole school or a year group - they usually have a range of purposes, such as to communicate information, encourage common spirit, and to present various subjects.

In this case they apparently had a school assembly on the subject of Internet safety, warning them about "weirdos" they may encounter online.